# Multiple tags in one line of align environment

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

Is there a possibility to tag each equation of a single line in an align environment of the amsmath package?

Like so (this code leads to the error `Package amsmath Error: Multiple \tag.`):

```
\begin{align}
  a &= b \tag{A} & c &= d \tag{B} \\
  e &= f \tag{C} & g &= h \tag{D}
\end{align}
```

Or is there any other environment or package that can be used to achieve the same effect?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166928/labeling-multiple-equations-per-row-of-a-table